# Spring Api Gateway custom filter not works

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm difficult to figure out with a problem in my api gateway service. I follow a lot of forum and documentatio to perform an easy implementation of a filter that is called via a specific predicates. In this step I just want to understand why the system.out in the filter class is not printed (that's mean that my yml not communicate correctly with the framerk and with the class of the filter I suppose).

This is the application.yml file:

```
server:
  port: 8080

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost

spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: identity-auth
          uri: http://localhost:8081/
          predicates:
            - Path=/auth/**
        - id: identity-time
          uri: http://localhost:8081/
          predicates:
            - Path=/timing/**
          filters:
            - Timing



debug: true
```

The class delegated to manage the TimingFilter:

```
@Component
public class TimingGatewayFilterFactory extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<TimingFilter.Config>{

    @Autowired
    TestService testService;

    public TimingFilter(){
        super(Config.class);
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        System.out.println("--------------here----------- ");
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            String originalPath = exchange.getRequest().getPath().toString();
            String newPath = "/timing/" + testService.evaluateCurrentDate();
            URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(exchange.getRequest().getURI()).path(newPath).build(true).toUri();
            ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest().mutate().uri(uri).build();
            return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).build());
        };
    }

    public static class Config {

    }
}
```

Without go into the question of redirect to the other microservice, in this step I want just to understand why after the GET REQUEST :

> http://localhost:8080/timing

I do not see the sout content when I performe the request, the print happend only one time in application startup.

Any suggestions? thanks

Comment: Rename `TimingFilter` to `TimingGatewayFilterFactory` and configure uit using ` - Timing`

Comment: Thank you but it solves just a portion of the problem, the print happened only once at the startup of application and not for each request that is linked to the filter...

Comment: Apply only happens once. Only things after the return statement happen on each filter request

Comment: the problem is that now the filter is called only at application startup... If I try to call the request, the filter is not invoked

Comment: The println only happens once as coded

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Service
public class BarFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(
            final ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange,
            final WebFilterChain webFilterChain
    ) {
        System.out.println("Filter works");
        return webFilterChain.filter(serverWebExchange);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
server:
  port: 8080

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost

spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: identity-auth
          uri: http://localhost:8081/
          predicates:
            - Path=/auth/**
        - id: identity-time
          uri: http://localhost:8081/
          predicates:
            - Path=/timing/**
      default-filters:
        - Timing
```